# "automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button"?

Tags: android

I would like to ask what the comment `automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button` in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method means.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [source code for `Activity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#2888) and more clearly in the [source code for `ActionBarActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.java#160), the base classes will automatically handle actions of hitting the [Up button](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) if you do not handle it yourself.

Comment: Which base classes, Sir?

Comment: When you write `MyActivity extends Activity`, `Activity` is called the base class (as in you are extending the baseline functionality of `Activity`).

Comment: Ah now I understand a bit. Just another sub-question: Can you choose to not specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml i.e. not make the parent activity handle the clicks to Home/Up button?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, but that's exactly the reason `ActionBarActivity` has methods like [onSupportNavigateUp()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#onSupportNavigateUp()), which allows you to customize the Up behavior in certain situations (or get a callback of when it happens).